# Debconf errors when configuring mysql-server

Tags: dpkg, mysql, debconf

When I try to run sudo apt-get upgrade I get the error below.

I also get similar error when running sudo reconfigure postfix, which I relly need to run since outgoing e-mail is not working any more. I have also run sudo apt-get autoclean, sudo apt-getclean, sudo apt-get install debconf --reinstall and sudo apt-get install -f without success.

```
magento@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install debconf --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server-5.5
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
28 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 149 kB/8,990 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main debconf all 1.5.46ubuntu1     [149 kB]
Fetched 149 kB in 0s (472 kB/s)
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line     46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 81482 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql-server-5.5 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 (using .../mysql-    server-5.5_5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.2_amd64.deb) ...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line     46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line     46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.28-    0ubuntu0.12.10.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line     46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at     /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.2_amd64.deb
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running Ubuntu 12.10.

Command df gives:

```
Filesystem                 1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/magento-root  53613052 6529812  44359812  13% /
udev                         3978932       4   3978928   1% /dev
tmpfs                        1595380     264   1595116   1% /run
none                            5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        3988440       0   3988440   0% /run/shm
none                          102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                     233191   53511    167239  25% /boot
```

I have seem post where it suggested to not use tmpfs for /var/cahce, if this is the problem, how can I configure Ubuntu to use my hard drive (and SSD) for /var/cache.

Thanks in advance for any help, and forgive me for my newbieness..

Update:

Running

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get install -f
```

gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server-5.5
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
28 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,840 kB of archives.
After this operation, 69.9 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line         46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 81482 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql-server-5.5 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.1 (using .../mysql-        server-5.5_5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.2_amd64.deb) ...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line         46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line         46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.28-         0ubuntu0.12.10.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line         46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at         /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.10.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 15):

I guess I am bit too late... but I'll post it anyway, in case someone comes here searching for the solution of the same problem.

`debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :No such file or directory` means `debconf` is missing it's directory in `/var/cache` which has been removed somehow (still cannot figure out how, considering it worked ok before).

One obvious solution would be to recreate it (`sudo mkdir /var/cache/debconf`), or reinstall debconf from package (really no need for that).

Comment: Exactly my issue, I accidentally deleted that folder and believed it's going to recreate itself when needed - well, it didn't. Thank you for posting the solution

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem (Ubuntu 13.04), it was because I delted (accidently) /var/cache/debconf
I just **recreated** it and all was peachy again... so:
/var/cache/debconf:
   missing = bad
   present = good

**[image]**

PS: cut and paste if you are lazy like me:

```
 sudo mkdir /var/cache/debconf
```

and I've found that some tools that claim to clean up hard drives go around deleting empty folders in places like /var/cache so...

```
sudo touch /var/cache/debconf/.dont-delete-this-directory
```

which of course then rmdir will be blocked when someone/something comes in and tries to get rid of it... of course the seasoned user knows to NEVER use optimization tools, especially on -nix based systems, that kind of crap is best left to the -dows crowd and their newbies, so most people reading this will probably be laughing at the thought of doing so... myself included (just bored i guess). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thank you @EliahKagan. Running the first command goes fine, however, the second command gives the error below (similar to the initial error message). Thanks again for any suggestions.

Comment: And thank you @user123418, I am not sure who answered this question of you two.

Comment: @audunms user123418 wrote this answer; I just edited it in a relatively minor way. (See [it's history](http://askubuntu.com/posts/244991/revisions).)

Comment: Thank you @EliahKagan, original post now updated with more info.

Comment: And I'll be happy if you have some input to the actual question also @EliahKagan :-)

Comment: And @user123418 :-)